# Could knowledge be transferred from deep learning models to deep reinforcement learning agent?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, transfer-learning

Transfer learning is recently widely investigated in reinforcement learning. However, in the literature, most articles (that I have read) have transferred knowledge from one RL agent to another RL agent where the tasks are similar. My question is, could transfer learning from a DL (not RL) model to a Deep RL agent be leveraged? For example, use an existant DL model as DRL agent's Deep Q network. Is it possible? because no paper to my knowledge uses this approach that's why I have a doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [behavior cloning](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/pretrain.html), in which you can pre-train RL policies using trajectories from an expert, and therefore accelerate training, in a supervised learning fashion.